# How to filter a listview corresponding to the user that is logged in?

Tags: php, android, listview

I have a listview show details from my server. And I want it to be filtered who is the poster. I have used a one-to-many relationship using username. PLease help me. Thanks here are my codes.

### ownerhome.class

```
package com.example.kun.carkila;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.amigold.fundapter.BindDictionary;
import com.amigold.fundapter.FunDapter;
import com.amigold.fundapter.extractors.StringExtractor;
import com.amigold.fundapter.interfaces.DynamicImageLoader;
import com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ownerhome extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
private ArrayList<Cars> carList;
private ListView lvCars;
private FunDapter<Cars> adapter;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ownerhome);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(ownerhome.this));
    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(ownerhome.this, this);
    taskRead.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/product.php");

    lvCars = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvOnwer);



    pref = getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Log.d(TAG, pref.getString("username", ""));
    Log.d(TAG, pref.getString("password", ""));

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(ownerhome.this, InsertActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater findMenuItems = getMenuInflater();
    findMenuItems.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.action_logout){
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent in = new Intent(ownerhome.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void processFinish(String s) {

    carList = new JsonConverter<Cars>().toArrayList(s,Cars.class);

    BindDictionary<Cars> dict = new BindDictionary<Cars>();

    dict.addDynamicImageField(R.id.ivImg, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return product.Image;
        }
    }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView); // Default options will be used

        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarModel, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Car Model: " + product.Car_Model;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarType, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Car Type: " + product.Car_Type;
        }
    });

    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCapacity, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Capacity: " + product.Capacity;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvFuelType, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Fuel Type: " + product.FuelType;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvPlateNumber, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Plate Number: " + product.PlateNumber;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvPoster, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Posted by: " + product.owner;
        }
    });


adapter = new FunDapter<>(
        ownerhome.this, carList, R.layout.layout_list, dict);

lvCars.setAdapter(adapter);
lvCars.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Cars selectedCars = carList.get(position);
    Intent in = new Intent(ownerhome.this, DetailActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("cars", selectedCars);
    startActivity(in);
}
}
```

Here is the php for the json

### product.php

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM car_category ORDER BY Car_No DESC"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

It only shows me all of the data in the database I want it to be filtered only from the username that is saved on the sharedpref. Thanks again guys :)

Comment: What is your real problem?? Are you getting data for all users in API call and you want to show only those corresponding to your user in app?

Comment: @Jas - This is just one of the feature of my app I want my users to see their own posts. But theirs also a listview to see all the posts.

Comment: @Jas - The real problem is I don't know how to show the user their own posts on their listview sir.

Comment: Are you saving the posts in your app db and showing them later?

Comment: @Jas - on the mysql database on my webhost sir.